# How to place a matrix as an element of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R that looks like the following:

```
a      b      c      out1      out2
0      1      0      NA        NA
1      0      1      NA        NA
1      1      0      NA        NA

DF <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,1), b= c(1,0,1), c = c(0,1,0), out1=NA, out2=NA)
```

I use the values of a, b, and c as inputs for a function that creates two matrices. Currently, if I try to assign one of the matrices to a cell in the dataframe (eg `dataframe$out1[1] <- matrix`) it seems to try and overwrite the dataframe with values from the matrix.

How can I store the matrices in these cells?

Comment: You may wrap it with `list` and write i.e. `dataframe$out[1] <- list(matrixObj)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap the `matrix` in a `list` and then assign it to the cell.

```
dataframe$out[1] <- list(matrixObj)
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!!